# Set url path on dynamic variable

Tags: android, variables

I have a TextView which contains 'F' or 'M', based on user selection. So in my activity I should have to assign a url path relatively to the letter in this TextView. I have created two static strings like so:

```
private static final String urlman = "http://www.example.com/man.php";
private static final String urlwoman = "http://www.example.com/woman.php";
```

Then I've created this control point:

```
private void controlsexuser() {
    String sexuser = sexController.getText().toString();
    sexController.setText(sexuser);
    if (sexuser.trim().equals("F")) {
        String sceltaServizio = urlwoman;
    }else {
        String sceltaServizio = urlman;
    }
}
```

Then in AsyncTask, I've tried to put the new string:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(sceltaServizio);
```

Unfortunately, the app stops and I don't know why. Any suggestions would be apreciated! Thanks

Comment: `sceltaServizio` is null

Comment: I could imagine...but i have put after string sceltaservizio = urlman a log and i can see that it isn't null...string is correct...

Comment: if `controlsexuser()` is the  code you are running, the some you posted, there is not way that `sceltaServizio` is not null in your `AsyncTask`

Comment: I have declared a string null sceltaservizio, and if i log it after run controlsexuser, it contains the url setted in urlman or url woman... Were is the error?

Comment: *and if i log it after run controlsexuser, it contains the url setted in urlman or url woman*, where are you logging it ?

Comment: Yes, it's correct, i don't know if it's wrong, i use Log.i("value",""+sceltaservizio)

Comment: @Karr You were right Johnie, as you can read below! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check the visibility(Access Modifier) of `sceltaServizio`.

Comment: sorry, i shouldn't know how do it

Comment: use log inside `AsyncTask` once and before `DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());`  line and check what value its returning.

Comment: Good suggestion! variable in AsyncTask has lost his value and is null. So, i have changed code, inserted a new textview and putted inside it value. It works properly now. Thanks